# Disagree with Edit Rejection Reasoning

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I recently attempted to edit [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26421274/css-circular-cropping-of-rectangle-image/26421723#26421723) with this [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12652108).  However, I don't feel my edit was reviewed correctly.  The reviewers rejected it on the reasoning that it deviated from the original intent of the post, but from the comments underneath the answer by the asker and answerer suggest that it actually was the intent of the post but at the time they didn't know how to do it.

However, I do realize that I'm a fairly new user and may be mistaken as to what defines the original intent of the post.  Also, I realized after my attempted edit that the answer was given a couple of years ago.  Could that be the reasoning behind it?

For now I have placed my suggestion in the comments.  If I am right, and the edit is fair, should I try to edit again? Or should I just leave it as is?

Comment: Try searching. The consensus is: don't edit code, unless there are various heavily upvoted comments pointing out a serious flaw that must be corrected, mention that you are applying a patch mentioned and agreed upon in comments, then hope that the moon is right and it'll still be rejected 9 out of 10 times. So, in short: don't edit code.

Comment: Sorry I didn't realize that.  I checked several of the related questions before posting and none of them mentioned this or anything helpful for my situation.

Comment: @CodeCaster would you mind posting this as an answer so I can accept?

Comment: Nah, it's a duplicate of [When should I make edits to code?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code), under _"Editing Code in Answers": Don't: Make the code do something different than what the answer says it does_. Or so I believe. I do actually believe that the edit makes the answer better, as you would expect a cropped image to be centered, but alas, that's just how it works.